# How to make setOnClickListener capable of updating value

Tags: android, textview, onclicklistener

I'm new in android and I need some help.

I have four textviews, and one of them is clickable:

```
clickableTextView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
```

`clickableTextView` has the value of `textview1`, but inside `setOnClickListener` the `clickableTextView` takes the value of `textview2` after the fisrt click, after the second click takes the value of `textview3` and so on..

Means that: the first time is clickable `textview1`, the second time is clickable `textview2`, the third time is `textview3` and so on..

but even why `clickableTextView` is taking the exact values, clickable is everytime the first textview, `setOnClickListener` is not updating the new value of `clickableTextView`. Can someone help me how can i do this?

HERE IS THE CODE:

```
correctAnswerHolder.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                Log.e("correctAnswerHolder", correctAnswerHolder.getText().toString());

                if ( i < list.size() )
                {
                    i++;
                    Log.e("i++", Integer.toString(i));

                    String question = list.get(i).getQuestion();
                    TextView questionText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.questionText);
                    questionText.setText(question);

                    String correctAnswer = list.get(i).getCorrectAnswer();
                    TextView correctAnswerText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.correctAnswerText);
                    Log.e("The Correct Answer", correctAnswer);
                    String wrongAnswer_1 = list.get(i).getWrongAnswer1();
                    TextView wrongAnswerText_1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.wrongAnswerText_1);
                    String wrongAnswer_2 = list.get(i).getWrongAnswer2();
                    TextView wrongAnswerText_2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.wrongAnswerText_2);
                    String wrongAnswer_3 = list.get(i).getWrongAnswer3();
                    TextView wrongAnswerText_3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.wrongAnswerText_3);

                    Uri imgUri = list.get(i).getImageURI();
                    ImageView imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);
                    imageView.setImageURI(imgUri);

                    final String [] answers = {correctAnswer, wrongAnswer_1, wrongAnswer_2, wrongAnswer_3};

                    ArrayList<String> answersList = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(answers));
                    long seed = System.nanoTime();
                    Collections.shuffle(answersList, new Random(seed));

                    Log.e("AnswersListSort ", answersList.toString());

                    correctAnswerText.setText(answersList.get(0));
                    wrongAnswerText_1.setText(answersList.get(1));
                    wrongAnswerText_2.setText(answersList.get(2));
                    wrongAnswerText_3.setText(answersList.get(3));

                    if (correctAnswerText.getText().toString().equals(correctAnswer)) correctAnswerHolder = correctAnswerText;
                    else if (wrongAnswerText_1.getText().toString().equals(correctAnswer)) correctAnswerHolder = wrongAnswerText_1;
                    else if (wrongAnswerText_2.getText().toString().equals(correctAnswer)) correctAnswerHolder = wrongAnswerText_2;
                    else if (wrongAnswerText_3.getText().toString().equals(correctAnswer)) correctAnswerHolder = wrongAnswerText_3;

                    Log.e("New correctAnswerHolder", correctAnswerHolder.getText().toString());
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Please post the entire affected code since this little 3-line-snippet won't help.

Comment: Thnx for replaying @MABVT. The code is to large and complex to understand simply, I don't wanna confuse all :/

Comment: Add whatever is inside the click listener so that we can see how you update the textviews.

Comment: In the Log.e("New correctAnswerHolder", correctAnswerHolder.getText().toString()); I get the exact output that should be, but is not updated to setOnClickListener..

Answer (score 0):

You can set all the TextViews as class attribute. Then, you can use the TextViews anywhere inside the Activity or fragment.

**Edit:**

Before post an example. What is correctAnswerHolder? Try to change the code like this:

```
if (correctAnswerText.getText().toString().equals(correctAnswer)) correctAnswerHolder.setText(correctAnswerText);
                    else if (wrongAnswerText_1.getText().toString().equals(correctAnswer)) correctAnswerHolder.setText(wrongAnswerText_1);
                    else if (wrongAnswerText_2.getText().toString().equals(correctAnswer)) correctAnswerHolder.setText(wrongAnswerText_2);
                    else if (wrongAnswerText_3.getText().toString().equals(correctAnswer)) correctAnswerHolder.setText(wrongAnswerText_3);
```

Comment: it doesn't work, correctAnswerHolder is the textview that has the correct answer, onclick of correctAnswerHolder the textviews are updating. Everything is ok, i tested with Log. but even when the correctAnswerHolder is updated, onClickListener is hold the first correctAnswerHolder.

Answer (score 0):

All of this code:

```
                TextView questionText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.questionText);
                TextView correctAnswerText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.correctAnswerText);
                TextView wrongAnswerText_1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.wrongAnswerText_1);
                TextView wrongAnswerText_2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.wrongAnswerText_2);
                TextView wrongAnswerText_3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.wrongAnswerText_3);
```

Should be in the Activity's onCreate() function:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity
{
    private TextView questionText;
    ...

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        super.onCreate(bundle);
        questionText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.myactivity_questiontext);
        ...
```

Or in the onCreateView() function of the Fragment, if you're using them:

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment
{
    private TextView questionText;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, something)
    {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.myfragment, container, false);
        questionText = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.myfragment_questiontext);
        ...
        return view;
    ...
```

Afterwards, it should probably work if you're already doing everything right.

Comment: The TextViews are all ok, everything is how it should. 

correctAnswerHolder.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                Log.e("correctAnswerHolder", correctAnswerHolder.getText().toString()); ---> I tested correctAnswerHolder to see if get the correct value and is ok, but the setOnClickListener remember the first click (TextView).