# Cannot assign value to final variable - Android

Tags: java, android, textview

I am trying to define a TextView final but says that: Cannot assign value to final variable.

In the code below i inserted some comments to help catching easier the problem.

Any help?

Thanks in advance!

CODE:

```
public class single_presentation extends Activity
{
    List<Slider> list;
    final TextView correctAnswerHolder = null;
    int i = 0;

    DatabaseHelper db = new DatabaseHelper(this);

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.single_presentation);

        String value = getIntent().getStringExtra("PRESENTATION_SESSION_ID");

        list = db.getAllSlidersByPresentation(value);
        db.close();

        String question = list.get(0).getQuestion();
        TextView questionText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.questionText);
        questionText.setText(question);

        String correctAnswer = list.get(0).getCorrectAnswer();
        TextView correctAnswerText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.correctAnswerText);
        String wrongAnswer_1 = list.get(0).getWrongAnswer1();
        TextView wrongAnswerText_1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.wrongAnswerText_1);
        String wrongAnswer_2 = list.get(0).getWrongAnswer2();
        TextView wrongAnswerText_2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.wrongAnswerText_2);
        String wrongAnswer_3 = list.get(0).getWrongAnswer3();
        TextView wrongAnswerText_3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.wrongAnswerText_3);

        Uri imgUri = list.get(i).getImageURI();
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        imageView.setImageURI(imgUri);

        final String [] answers = {correctAnswer, wrongAnswer_1, wrongAnswer_2, wrongAnswer_3};

        ArrayList<String> answersList = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(answers));
        long seed = System.nanoTime();
        Collections.shuffle(answersList, new Random(seed));

        Log.e("First Slider Answers ", answersList.toString());

        correctAnswerText.setText(answersList.get(0));
        wrongAnswerText_1.setText(answersList.get(1));
        wrongAnswerText_2.setText(answersList.get(2));
        wrongAnswerText_3.setText(answersList.get(3));

        if (correctAnswerText.getText().toString().equals(correctAnswer))
            correctAnswerHolder = correctAnswerText; // HERE is the problem
        else if (wrongAnswerText_1.getText().toString().equals(correctAnswer))
            correctAnswerHolder = wrongAnswerText_1; // HERE is the problem
        else if (wrongAnswerText_2.getText().toString().equals(correctAnswer))
            correctAnswerHolder = wrongAnswerText_2; // HERE is the problem
        else if (wrongAnswerText_3.getText().toString().equals(correctAnswer))
            correctAnswerHolder = wrongAnswerText_3; // HERE is the problem
```

Comment: yes you can't, why you want declare that as `final`?

Comment: Do you really know `Java`? You need to read Java Programming book!

Comment: i want to utilize it in correctAnswerHolder.setOnClickListener in order to get changes of correctAnswerHolder.

Comment: remove `final` and go on.

Comment: A reference variable declared final can never be reassigned to refer to an different object.

Comment: declare TextView and String as Global Varibales.

Answer (score 0):

If you declare a variable final it can only be assigned once.

more info:
http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/synchronization_final.shtml

Comment: Thank you @Deacovy, I have read somewhere to declare the textview final in order to solve my problem..

Please give a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24361042/how-to-make-setonclicklistener-capable-of-updating-value

Answer (score 0):

Any variable declared final in java can not be reassigned a value. Here you are first assigning null to your variable so you cannot change it.
can you please elaborate why you declared your variable final?

Comment: This is not an answer..rather it should be a comment.